# How to globally override compiler in qmake with subprojects?

Tags: qt5, qmake, ccache

Can I somehow override define `QMAKE_CXX` globally for all subprojects of a .pro file?

Placing this statement to the top project file did not change the compiler in subprojects. It only works if I copy it to every .pro file.

I would like to define `QMAKE_CXX = ccache $$QMAKE_CXX` using a command line argument for `qmake`

Comment: I'd strongly advise to either create a custom mkspec, or, in the case of ccache, to properly set it up so that it's found when invoking `gcc` or `g++` or `clang++` and so on. Anyhow, a simple workaround could be adding that line into a `.qmake.cache` file in the top level of your project. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-environment-reference.html#cache-file

Comment: I just found out that Qt already does what I want by calling `qmake CONFIG+=ccache ../project`. I have no idea why that config switch exists.